# Use var everywhere in file/project/solution not working

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.1) and Resharper 2018 (2018.1) and am trying to run the command "Use var" but apply it accross the entire solution. I use the left hand side "hammer" icon and select "Use var" and tell it to apply across the solution. A dialog appears "Applying in scope" and seems to scan all my source files, but then only changes the line that I originally selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "hammer" icon I use the "lightbulb" icon and it works as expected. I have no idea why. Hopefully someone can come up with the proper solution

[image]

Place your cursor on the end of the type name to get the hammer icon on the left hand side (bad)

MyType{cursor here} varibleName = something();

Place the cursor somewhere inside the type declartion to get the lightbulb icon on the left hand

MyT{cursor here}ype varibleName = something();